# Mysql 5.7 checking user credentials via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, hash, authentication

i am beginner in `PHP` and `MySQL`. I am trying validate user inputs (Username and Password) in MySQL 5.7 DB but no chance. Let me explain my problem;

I created a user in `firstdb` with username: `firstuser` password: `firstpassword` via `phpMyAdmin` page.

**CODE (check_user-pass.php)**

```
<?php
ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="rootpassword"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="firstdb"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="mysql.user"; // Table name

$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

// Define $username and $password 
$myusername=$_POST['EMail']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['Password'];


// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['EMail']);
$mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['Password']);


$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user='$myusername' and authentication_string='$mypassword'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$count = 0;

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $count);

    /* close result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
if ($count==1) {
    echo "Success! $count";
} else {
    echo "Unsuccessful! $count";

}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

**Code return:** `Connected successfullyResult set has 0 rows. Unsuccessful! 0`

If i remove this line: `and authentication_string='$mypassword'`**Code return:** `Connected successfullyResult set has 1 rows. Success! 1`

I succesfully retrieve user inputs from `index.php` to `check_user-pass.php` but there is no clear password column in `mysql.user` table for matching in database.

I search over net and find; `password` column changed to `authentication_string` in 5.x but this column carry the hashed thing. So i can't match the user password with this.

**Question 1**

Should i create a table and store the username and clear password for every user in DB for validating?

**Question 2**

If question1 answer is NO, how can achieve this validation problem?

Comment: _store [...] clear password_ - NO! Never, ever, under any circumstances store clear passwords.

Comment: In think same too.

Comment: It's not advisable to escape passwords, especially when it comes to ones such as `123'\abc` being perfectly valid. In escaping those, it will rewrite it as `123\'\abc` in turn failing on `password_verify()`, if and when you use `password_hash()` to store the hashed password with. In either case; it still stands to fail.

Answer (score -2):

I've done so many logins for people I just wrote a class for myself, its on github if you're interested
https://github.com/wazimshizm/secure-login

for easiest out of the box authentication, use this for storing & comparing passwords:

```
password_hash($passwordVariable, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
password_verify($inputPassword, $storedPassword);
```

Comment: Sure i will check this. But actually i want to learn basic things about matching credentials. Thank you anyway.

Comment: updated the answer, everything you need for passwords